# State of the art of cheap lists operations in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, data-structures

For cheap operations like `append` on lists (not character strings), I would use Data.DList.
What holds me back is that the package on Hackage is marked “experimental” and the last update was in 2009.

Is DList still the way to go for that in Haskell?

Comment: What are the operations you expect O(1) complexity from?

Comment: If all you are interested in is append then I recommend this function: `append x y = undefined`, it's very fast. :)  So I assume you want to do something after you have constructed the list.  Once you tell us what that is we can give you advice.

Comment: @augustss: :) It's about building and converting lists of structured text. Not plain Data.Text, but lists of say 'Bold "hi there"', 'Paragraph "Long boring text"' or 'Section "Title" "Content..."'.

Comment: @Lenny222 So how about building a tree with a text item in each leaf and then each append generates a fork.  That gives you constant time append.  You can linearise it later in O(n) time, i.e., amortized O(1) per append.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Seq from [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). It also has O(1) cons and snoc, but it is in base, and is used and tested a lot more.

Answer (score 6):

[Data.DList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.5) seems to have been last updated at Sat Jun 20 23:01:49 UTC 2009.
Pretty many useful things in hackage are marked experimental, but I wouldn't worry about that. DList seems quite solid. It uses none of the volatile language extensions and the code is actually quite simple.

So, I guess, the answer would be: yes, DList is still good.

Comment: 2009: My mistake, somehow Google sent me to an older version. I wonder whether it has bitroded, during the GHC -> 7.* upgrades.

Comment: @Lenny222: I doubt that it's bitrotted.  A difference list is pretty simple and the package doesn't seem to use any GHC extensions except CPP.  There isn't likely to be much that could go wrong.